# How to lock formula-values (IF statement) even with cell values changeable? (Google Sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a IF formula (=if(A3="ACTIVE",NOW(),)), how do I lock the time column to be the first datestamp captured while my status column values are changeable? Is this only possible with a google AppScript? I have no experience with AppScript and looking for someone to help with the script.

| Status | Time |
| --- | --- |
| ACTIVE | 4/20/2023 16:52:17 |
| INACTIVE | 4/20/2023 16:52:17 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to enable iterative calculations, you can get the desired behaviour without using AppScript. If so, the following formula will capture the datestamp only from the first time A3 is set to ACTIVE and will not change with any subsequent changes:

```
=if(and(A3="ACTIVE",not(B3)),now(),if(B3,B3,))
```

This works because of the following properties:

1. When iterative calculations are enabled, the default value of a self-referencing formula is 0
2. Dates in Sheets are internally calculated as datetime serial numbers since the beginning of the epoch starting 30th December 1899
3. In a Boolean evaluation, Sheets considers 0 or blank as falsy, and any other numerical value (including a datetime serial number) as truthy

So if A3 is not marked 'ACTIVE' the outer IF must be FALSE and the inner IF will be evaluated; this evaluates B3 as TRUE if there is anything other than the default zero/blank (falsy) value and in this case just maintains whatever value is already present, else FALSE (which results in a blank cell  because we have left the value_if_false argument empty). In order to write the datestamp into B3 the outer IF must be true, and this is only the case when A3 is marked as ACTIVE *and* B3 is falsy, in which case the value of NOW is written into B3. After this point the outer IF can never be true again, so the datestamp will never change.

Comment: Hi I tried your method but now() shows me 12/30/1899, how do I fix this

Comment: That's because you have the 'Time' column set to a date/time format - if it's set to 'automatic' this doesn't happen. However I've now worked out how to hide the initial state in any case - please see the updated answer.

Comment: It works omg! Can you help to explain the formula, sorry I still dont really get it...

Comment: I've added some additional explanation to the answer. I've also been able to compact the formula down even further as well :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the formula and couldnt appreciate enough for the explanation!